# Grails executeUpdate with Limit doesn't work for deletion

Tags: sql, grails, hql

I'm trying to do something like this in Grails HQL but it doesn't work

I want to remove up-to 5 elements out of list of IDs which could contain 10 elements. I order them by date and delete only the oldest 5

```
Entity.executeUpdate(
        "DELETE FROM Entity WHERE id in (:list) ORDER BY date LIMIT 5",
        [list: oldestIdsForRemoval])
```

Pure SQL works just fine

```
DELETE FROM entity WHERE id in ('8f027db299354a869af51e1f0a60ede1', '96df61161c32491f8aa4a14c5017852c', '88aa7b2bb6e1444f8d892fff10b8adcd') ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Is this even possible?
I've tried also adding `max:5` parameter to the list of parameters, but it fails.

I'm using Grails 1.3.6 . If it is fixed in newer version, would be good to know , although I cannot use it.
Documentation doesn't help much in this regard: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html

Answer (score 1):

When working with HQL, consider using Hibernate's User Guide. It contains a section on HQL which covers the language pretty well. Here's the root directory: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/

Another source, though a more cryptic one, is the ANTLR source for the parser used to parse HQL code: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/antlr/hql.g

It is from the ANTLR code that you may arrive at the conclusion, as I did, that HQL does not support `LIMIT`. This being the case, you have a couple of options:

1. Use two queries. A `SELECT`, along with a max, to select the IDs, and then a `DELETE` for those specific IDs.
2. Use a native query instead (ex. SQL) to give you full access to the underlying database.